# Can you be arraigned for felony charges that you have not been arrested for?

Tags: arrest

The question I have relates to the fact that a warrant was issued for my arrest. When I received notice if this, I then notified the court that I have received such notice. At this point the court appointed clerk scheduled me on the docket to be arraigned. After being arraigned on felony charges, I had attended two separate continuances. Then the judge had noticed that I have never been arrested for the crime that I had just pled not guilty to at the arraignment. Upon noticing this the judge orders me for a book and release. Is it normal to be arraigned on charges when you have never been arrested for the crime?

Answer (score 2):

An arrest is not a legal prerequisite for an arraignment.

It may be, as a matter of policy, expected that someone charged with a felony be booked in order to obtain personal identifying information about a defendant (such as fingerprints and a mug shot) to facilitate the arrest of that person if they fail to appear in the future, but this is generally a matter of policy and not a legal requirement.